# Editing the ~/.bashrc file for hadoop installation

Tags: command-line, 16.04, hadoop, user-management

I have been trying to install hadoop-2.6.0 in my Ubuntu 16.04 machine.
I have been logged into the `hduser` from another user `krishna` by:

```
sudo su hduser
```

and the `hduser` then gets into its use.

After that i entered the command:

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

This opens the file in read-only mode but I am not getting the write access so that I can append a set of statements into it.

Comment: Have you tried `vi /home/hduser/.bashrc`?

Comment: I tried this one also but it didn't workout well enough

Comment: Are you a root user? is hduser root user?

Comment: What is the output of`ls -l /home/hduser/.bashrc`? Could you have possibly used root account to create the file (maybe though a script)? Then most likely `sudo chown hduser /home/hduser/.bashrc` will resolve the problem.

Comment: It worked fine using: '''sudo nano ~/.bashrc'''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To troubleshoot you should first run the command:

```
ls -l /home/hduser/.bashrc
```

It will display:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 hduser   186 Jun 27 15:27 /home/hduser/.bashrc
```

The first column (`-rw-r--r--`) lists permissions, the third one (`hduset`) the file owner.
If the owner is not `hduser` but `root`, you'd need to run:

```
sudo chown hduser /home/hduser/.bashrc
```

If there was a `hduser` listed as the owner, but permissions would not contain `w`, you'd need to run:

```
sudo chmod u+w /home/hduser/.bashrc
```

Comment: It did worked out using the nano editor and seems like vim had a problem with it....